# ADODB recordset SQL returns error in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, vba, csv, ado

The following code produces an error (Method 'Open' of object'_Recordset' failed) when I get to the statement that tries to open the recordset:

```
Set objClubSalesSourceConn = CreateObject("ADODB.COnnection")
objClubSalesSourceConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & strDirectory & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""
Set rsClubOrders = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strSQL = "SELECT"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Order Number] AS OrderNum,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Submitted Date] AS SaleDate,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Product SKU] AS SKU,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Product Name] AS ItemDesc,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Ext Item Price] AS SaleAmt,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Ext Item Shipping] AS ShipAmt,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    CASE WHEN ISNULL(ClubSales.[Ship Date])"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "        THEN 1"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "        ELSE 0 END AS ShipDateNull,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Ship Date] AS ShipDate,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Pickup Date] AS PickupDate,"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSales.[Quantity Sold] * ClubSales.[Cost Of Goods] AS COGSAmt"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "FROM"
strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & "    ClubSalesSource.csv AS ClubSales"

rsClubOrders.Open strSQL, objClubSalesSourceConn, adOpenDynamic*
```

The problem lies in the CASE WHEN statement in the SQL.  If I leave that out, the recordset opens okay.  I am in Excel VBA, querying a csv file.  I need to know how to fix this.  I have also unsuccessfully tried using an IIF function like I have done in Access.

Comment: IIF(isnull(x),true,false) ?

Comment: Yes, though now when I try that it works.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Jet/ACE does not support `CASE` statements. Show us the `IIF` that fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
strSQL = "SELECT" & _
"    ClubSales.[Order Number] AS OrderNum," & _
"    ClubSales.[Submitted Date] AS SaleDate," & _
"    ClubSales.[Product SKU] AS SKU," & _
"    ClubSales.[Product Name] AS ItemDesc," & _
"    ClubSales.[Ext Item Price] AS SaleAmt," & _
"    ClubSales.[Ext Item Shipping] AS ShipAmt," & _
"    CASE WHEN ISNULL(ClubSales.[Ship Date])" & _
"        THEN 1" & _
"        ELSE 0 END AS ShipDateNull," & _
"    ClubSales.[Ship Date] AS ShipDate," & _
"    ClubSales.[Pickup Date] AS PickupDate," & _
"    ClubSales.[Quantity Sold] * ClubSales.[Cost Of Goods] AS COGSAmt"  & _
" FROM" & _
"    ClubSalesSource.csv AS ClubSales"
```